# Is it possible to PUT JSP Code inside HTML Page?

Tags: jsp

I have a sample HTML File as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hi How are you 
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to put JSP code inside the aboev HTML File as shown below , which i will be using for Authentication purpose

```
<%!
System.out.println("Hi How are you 22222222");
session.setAttribute("LOGIN_USER", "user"); 
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Hi How are you 
</body>
</html>
```

But this is not working ( I mean it is not setting that value and Hi How are you 22222222 is not getting printed also )

Could you  please let me know hpw to put JSP Code inside HTML File ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `<%!` allows only to declare variable and methods. Change it to `<%`.

So your code should look like:

```
<%
System.out.println("Hi How are you 22222222");
session.setAttribute("LOGIN_USER", "user"); 
%>
```